# ASP.net wepage using spotify

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to ASP.net. I am trying to build a webform that searches an artist and displays their top 5 songs from spotify. My biggest problem as of now is figuring out where to put the code and what code to use so that I can receive this data from spotify. I have already made a spotify developer account with an app. I have the client ID and Client Secret. I think I need to figure out a way to authenticate. Any help or websites that could point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Why not read the actual Spotify API docs, it will have everything you need.
Just looking at https://developer.spotify.com/ the entire top of the page is trying to push you to the docs and I'm even seeing they provide web console to test out code and ideas.

Comment: I have to do this for an assignment. It would be much easier that way.

Comment: I guess my point is that you asked for some websites with info.... there is no better option then the source of truth aka the actual docs themselves.

Comment: Yeah ive gone through the docs of web api many times but its not giving me enought information. Would you be able to help me with sending a valid OAuth access token.

Comment: For that you need to ask a new question tagged with OAUTH. The question is far to broad to provide anything resembling a quick answer. Hopefully this can help you a little bit -> https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/

Comment: Also this tool would be very useful for you, it allows you to create web requests without having to actually write code so you can run tests and try things out before you commit to doing the code work itself -> https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: thank you very much